# What are the fines / penalties for having two people in the front passenger seat?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving, speeding

There were two people in the front passenger seat of the car.
To clarify, there were two (***"adult"***) individuals in the **same seat** wearing the same **seat-belt** and both were U.K. citizens and I am also an ***"adult"*** who is a U.K. citizen.

**NOTE:** Yes, I did go 5-15 MPH over the limit at one point or another.

I know this is reckless behaviour and that I shouldn't be doing such stupid things... So please don't lecture me over this.

I have a few questions on the matter:

- How *illegal* is this? (I.E: is it as bad as a severe offence or a minor mis-demeanour)
- What is the possibility of me getting caught?
- If I'm caught what fines and / or penalties can I expect?
- What's the *absolute worst* that could happen as a consequence of my actions?
- Could it be possible for me to get away with a warning?
- Could I get my licence revoked? (:/)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UK seat belt law is [here](https://www.gov.uk/seat-belts-law/overview).

What you were doing is illegal and carries a fine of £500.

As to your specific questions:

> How illegal is this?

It is not a criminal offence in any way.

> What is the possibility of me getting caught?

If a police officer notices you will almost certainly be booked. What is the possibility of being noticed? Depends where you are.

> If I'm caught what fines and / or penalties can I expect?

£500

> What's the absolute worst that could happen as a consequence of my actions?

You could crash and your passengers could die, you would then go to jail for dangerous driving occasioning death. Having 2 people in a seat belt is *extremely* hazardous - it would be far safer (but still illegal) to have one person in the seat belt and the other one unrestrained.

> Could it be possible for me to get away with a warning?

No

> Could I get my licence revoked? (:/)

Seat belts offences do not carry a points penalty so, of itself, it would not lead to loss of your licence.

Comment: I appreciate your "absolutely worst" response. I've given similar responses in real life to clients asking me questions like "what is the worst thing that can happen if I put a padlock on the emergency exit to my disco?"

Comment: Actually, no. That's the second-to-worst consequence. The worst consequence is that _everybody dies_, you included.